# Why did the most important lords want this character freed?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the season 8 episode finale of *Game of Thrones* the highest important lords met with Grey Worm to free

> Tyrion and Jon. While it was pretty clear why they wanted to free Jon it was unclear to me why they also asked for Tyrion.

To make things even more strange, they asked about his opinion of a potential solution which becomes the actual final one in the end

> (choose king and nominate someone).

I thought they (besides Sansa and Bran) don't like him and wanted to judge him? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but it seems that Tyrion is also the heir of the Lannister title, so he might have something to say in the concil as such.

Comment: yeah I've realized that later - Lannisters were an important lords as well..

Answer (score 11):

I get the impression they actually didn't as Tyrion himself states:

> **Tyrion:** Me? The Imp? Half the people hate me for serving Daenerys, the other half hate me for betraying her.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 6, "The Iron Throne"</sub>

And in actual fact I don't think they were actually trying to free him, he was brought there, at trial, so they could decide what to do with him whether that was freeing him or punishment or something else.

> Where's Jon?
>
> **Grey Worm:** He is our prisoner.
>
> **Sansa:** So is Lord Tyrion.
>
> **Grey Worm:** They were both to be brought to this gathering. We will decide what we do with our prisoners. This is our city now.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 6, "The Iron Throne"</sub>

They also then don't ask Tyrion for his opinion on what to do, he just sees an opportunity and gives it.

> **Tyrion:** Jon committed his crime here. His fate is for our king to decide. Or our queen.
>
> **Yohn Royce:** We don't have a king or queen.
>
> **Tyrion:** You're the most powerful people in Westeros. Choose one.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 6, "The Iron Throne"</sub>

Lastly, Tyrion goes free because Bran appoints him Hand of the King and so decides he should go free. As king he can do that, not because everyone there wanted him to go free.

> **Bran:** Lord Tyrion you will be my Hand.
>
> **Tyrion:** N-- No, Your Grace, I don't want it.
>
> **Bran:** And I don't want to be king.
>
> **Tyrion:** I don't deserve it. I thought I was wise, but I wasn't. I thought I knew what was right, but I didn't. Choose Ser Davos. Choose anyone else.
>
> **Bran:** I choose you.
>
> **Tyrion:** You cannot.
>
> **Bran:** Yes, I can. I'm king.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 8 Episode 6, "The Iron Throne"</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Who else can suggest better?

**Samwell Tarly:** he did try but nobody cared.

**Sansa Stak:** No experience in politics and barely survived from Ramsay. Even north picked Jon over her. And at this point, she seems to only care for the freedom of north.

**Edmure Tully:** Cough cough red wedding, not a chance and Sansa shut him up easily.

**Arya Stark:** an assassin who other lords bearly know.

**Bran Stark:** he came to become king as he said so why he will object.

**Ser Brienne of Tarth:** just a KNight from a house which barely matters now.

**Ser Davos Seaworth:** A pirate seriously?

Gendry Baratheon: he just becomes a lord of an almost extinct house.

**Yara Greyjoy:** Grejoy just earned some respect after her father's defeat long back

**Robin Arryn** He is still just an immature kid
Rest were some newcomers.

**Yohn Royce** not so much of a lord but an adviser

So Tyrion seems the most experienced person, served as Hand twice and considered a good adviser so why not ask him?

Comment: They didn't ask him though, he just gave his opinion on what to do.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot my point is who else can even tehy ask if tehy have to?

Comment: Ask themselves, there's enough there that they could discuss it themselves, or ask the Masters. There are other options but it doesn't matter because it never got to the stage of asking.

Comment: Sansa has no experience in politics? All she has done the whole series is get experience in politics. In fact, she learned the most from the best, Littlefinger.

Comment: You have Sansa twice...

Comment: @ArnaudD. nice catch, fixed